# Mongodb shopping cart, how to check and update inventory

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I read the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/inventory-management/) concerning the ways to implement a shopping cart with mongodb, but I have doubts about the flow.

With this implementation each time a user enters the products in the cart, the amount paid reserved to the customer is not available to other buyers until the user performs checkout or shopping cart expires.

This approach is a problem because, by experience, the majority of users do not buy the end, leaving for a period those products reserved only to him and therefore not affordable.
This translates into a loss of sales.

E.g:

- there is a product with 5 quantities in db
- a client "A" puts the product in the basket with amount 5
- then in the db are 0 products available
- another client "B" enter the site and can not buy that product
- in the end the customer "A" leave the site leaving the cart full.
- The shopping cart will automatically clear after an hour.

**Result: an hour for that product can not be purchased by anyone!**

I think a better approach is to inspect and updates only on the actual amount at checkout.
In this way you are not lost sales for too long.

The problem with this approach is the implementation at the atomic updates of the amount.

What do you think about this approach?
Are you planning an implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I'd use multiple records in the same collection for each product put in the cart, but with a 10 min TTL on an index for documents of type "in-cart" (see mongo TTL docs). Then, using db.col.aggregate(...) you can sum these records and deduct the count from the total available. If a user leaves without buying, the TTL will auto delete de document. If he buys, you can really deduct from the total available using doc.update and $inc with negative value and delete the associated in-cart documents.

product document:

```
{
  type: 'product'
  product_id: 123,
  available: 4
}
```

in-cart document(s) as many as "in progress shopping" or abandonned carts:

```
{
  type: 'in-cart'
  product_id: 123,
  customer_id: 1,
  taken: 2
}

{
  type: 'in-cart'
  product_id: 123,
  customer_id: 2,
  taken: 1,
}
```